# Home NAS RAM questions

Tags: memory, motherboard, nas, ecc

Just trying to build a Home NAS system with the Ryzen 3 2200G CPU and ASROCK AB350 Gaming-ITX/ac board. Since I'm going to use ZFS, I guess the ECC memory is a must-have.

As I'm quite new to building systems, could you please give me some advice on the following questions?

1. Both CPU and Motherboard support the ECC RAM, but I'm unable to tell if the support is for ECC registered or ECC unregistered DIMM.  Where could I find such info, or can I just simply get the ECC registered DIMM
2. Will this Kingston RAM (KVR24R17S4L/8MB) work for the above setup?  I'm unable to find any reviews on this, but based on the production description it seems to be fine.
   [Link to Kingston memory specification](https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR24R17S4L_8MB.pdf)

Comment: I see the ASROCK website says MB only supports Unbuffed ECC DIMM, will there be any issues to use Buffed ECC DIMM?

Comment: Go to the Kingston memory site,punch in your motherboard details and it will tell you what RAM is compatible.

Comment: Thanks, let me have a check.  Last time I checked they've only got it for Server boards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further searching, confirmed the following points:

ECC RDIMM will not work on ECC UDIMM slots, the PC won't boot up.

KVR24E17S8/8MA will work for my above configuration.